# Launching Minipar

Tags: java, nlp, tokenize, gate, part-of-speech

I would like to use Minipar parser, the POS module and especially the pronoun resolution parser (coreferrence resolution). I use Windows 10, and I downloaded the GATE version containing Minipar : GATE_Developer_8.1. I followed the user manual but could not run the parser in GATE interface. Can someone provide  some help? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO - but I'm not sure that this question falls within acceptable parameters. Please read the help pages, an consider if this question can be reworked to fit within those guidelines.

Comment: What dou you mean by:
_could not run the parser in GATE interface_ ?

Comment: @dedek: I mean that I opened Gate window, I loaded a document, I loaded Minipar, and then the documentation says to press on "Run" but I cannot find the "Run" button. I know I downloaded the last version of Gate, so I do not think the problem be due to the fact that the version I use is obsolete.

Comment: @Catalina: I think you just didn't find the "Run" button. See following screen cast, on **frame 53** the user is just hitting the button :-)  https://gate.ac.uk/g8/page/print/2/demos/developer-videos/videos/UK-video05/Module5_Applications.htm

Comment: All the videos can be found here: https://gate.ac.uk/demos/developer-videos/